# How to maximize GNOME Terminal on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gnome-terminal

Environment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux, C language , Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Question: I'm programming a typing tutor which run on GNOME terminal, i want to maximize      terminal when run the program(on GNOME). How can i realize it, does anyone have suggestions or any possible clues.

Comment: gnome-terminal  --full-screen might help

Comment: I really think this belongs on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ gnome-terminal --maximize
```

Should do.

Take a look at

```
$ gnome-terminal --help
$ gnome-terminal --help-window-options
```

etc. to see what else you can do.

---

So you want to run your application *inside* a maximized GNOME terminal? The easiest way is to seperate launching the application from the code itself.

Write a shellscript wrapper which runs `gnome-terminal --maximize -x my_typing_tutorial`. Then set up the shortcut (or whatever) to run this script, instead of your binary.

Note this gives you a chance to detect if gnome-terminal isn't installed, and try starting konsole or xterm instead. It also means that a user can edit the start script if it doesn't work on their system, without having to re-compile your binary.

Note that I'm not addressing the question of how to maximize an existing terminal - if I were the user, I'd hate a program that messed up my window geometry without asking.

Comment: Thank for your graciously help.                                                    But seems like doesn't work, maybe i haven't described my problem clearly.As u may know, i'm using C language to program. What i expected is to maximum GNOME terminal when starting typing tutor(by pressing an START/OK button), not maximum terminal by Initialization. Which means if i can write some C language code to realize it, like by calling "system("clear)";" to clear terminal screen.                                                                   Thank u again.

Comment: yeah, that's what i exactly wanted-the solutions & suggestions. u r right, i should consider about the protability and maximize my GNOME without user's permission is not a good idea, though the program is just a demo that my leader ask me to try.  Thank you again.   In the end, how can i change my text to a new line like u did... it's ugly without a proper new-line just as what i did...

Comment: If you mean the formatting, you have only limited control in comments. In questions and answers, just look at the help to see what you can do.

Comment: Here in 2021, that switch is not even listed in the man page; had to find it with `gnome-terminal --help-all`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use wmctrl, to get current window id use `$WINDOWID` environment variable,
to get current window geometry use `xwinfo -id $WINDOWID`

so after something like `sudo aptitude install wmctrl` :

- `wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b toggle,fullscreen` #toggle fullscreen
- `wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b add,fullscreen` #force fullscreen
- `wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b remove,fullscreen` #force remove fullscreen

Also wmctrl have own way to handle current window:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen
```

Comment: well, thank u for ur help, i just tried as told, but seems nothing changed except "xwinfo -id $WINDOWID" shows my window information.Since i have installed wmctrl1.7, i don't know what happened though.

Comment: what you using gnome or kde ? in kde all works even for xterm
my wmctrl version is 1.07

Comment: eh, i'm using gnome, my vmctrl is also 1.07. but when tried :     wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b toggle,fullscreen - toggle fullscreen             wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b add,fullscreen - force fullscreen       wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b remove,fullscreen - force remove fullscree    nothingh happened, i dont know why...

Comment: did you tried just
`wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b toggle,fullscreen`
?

Comment: actually, i tried what u said, still nothing happened, seems "wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID" doesn't get window ID(though -i get numerical ID and -x get string ID), but "xwinfo -id $WINDOWID" first to get window ID and then try "swmctrl -r "current WINDOWID" -b add,fullscreen", it works, both toggle and add works.

Comment: $WINDOWID should just have current windowid, xwinfo is just tool that uses that variable

Comment: $WINDOWID is 44040210. xvinfo show 0x2a00012 (same in hexadecimal) 
both
`wmctrl -i -r 0x2a00012 -b toggle,fullscreen` and `wmctrl -i -r 44040210 -b toggle,fullscreen` works same way. check `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen`

Comment: my terminal shows: Window id: xwininfo: Window id: 0x1b7268a "root@localhost:~"
and "wmctrl -i -r 0x1b7268a -b toggle,fullscreen" didn't work but "wmctrl -r root@localhost:~/CWrokspace/Debug -b toggle,fullscreen"(if with '-i' it shows error:Cannot convert argument to number.) did.
"wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen" work too, just as @Useless said, maybe i can read help tutor more careful, since have got the way, i'm sorry about taking much of ur time and thanks a lot for ur instant help.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10 in a gnome terminal this works perfectly. `wmctrl -l` shows the available windows. And e.g. `wmctrl -i -r 0x05000682 -b toggle,fullscreen` makes the window full screen. The `:ACTIVE:` handle does not work though. Ah, I see it DOES work, but then the `-i` flag has to be removed.

Comment: maximizing the terminal is not quite the same as fullscreen. i want the same as op, to maximize the terminal, not fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a launcher called it "Gnome Terminal Maximized" for your desktop and double-click on it. This is how to do it:

```
cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop|sed 's/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal --maximize/;s/Name=Terminal/& Maximized/' > ~/Desktop/gnome-terminal-maximized.desktop
```

Comment: thank u for the same. Actually i did't get u properly, well , i'm just a newbie about LINUX, people here are really enthusastic. Thk u all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xdotool utility.

You can run xdotool code that automatically moves the mouse to the upper left corner of the active window, double clicks and the moves back, in a fraction of a second. The code is the following:

```
#get the active windows id.
active_window_id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
#get current x and y mouse locations.
cx=$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell | grep X | sed s/X=//gi);
cy=$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell | grep Y | sed s/Y=//gi);

#move to upper left corner of current window.
xdotool mousemove --window ${active_window_id} 50 -10;
#double click.
xdotool click 1;
xdotool click 1;
#move back to original location with the mouse.
xdotool mousemove ${cx} ${cy};
```

You can then put this code into a start_script and then run that file by putting the following in your ~/.bashrc:

```
start(){
    /path/your_start_script
    }
```

The when you run this start command the terminal becomes maximized. You can also insert whatever other commands you want to happen when you start a terminal.

You can install xdotool with:
sudo apt-install xdotool;